# simplexml_load_file() returns empty object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a url to an xml file and when I visit it in my browser it looks good. With the following script however a lot of information seems to be missing:

```
<?php

    $xml_url = "example.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);
    print_r($xml);

?>
```

What's going wrong?

EDIT: when I view the xml file in my browser, the data is shown between these: `<![CDATA[   ]]>` 
Maybe that helps.

Comment: Hey Bart, nope :( here's a screenshot of the result: http://gyazo.com/35c34353459497f74d9448b859cd2710.png

Answer (score 6):

The `print()` call does not display all information. Do

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```